# configure qiskit on win10 error:numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

Tags: python-3.x, lapack, quantum-computing, qiskit

I’m new to python and I got some problem when trying to install QISKit.

First, I was using `pip install qiskit` on cmd, but it showed an error

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

I searched on internet and `pip install scipy` separately. It worked

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.0.0-cp36-none-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in 
d:\programming\python\lib\site-packages (from scipy)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.0.0
```

Then I tried `pip install qiskit` again. It showed an error:

```
Found existing installation: scipy 1.0.0
Uninstalling scipy-1.0.0:
  Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.0.0
Running setup.py install for scipy ... error

……

numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of scipy
```

So I used the second way:

```
git clone https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py

cd qiskit-sdk-py
```

then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

again

```
Installing collected packages: scipy, sympy
  Found existing installation: scipy 1.0.0
    Uninstalling scipy-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.0.0
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error

……

    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
     Rolling back uninstall of scipy
```

how can I solve this and add QISKit to python lib?

reference:
https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py/blob/master/doc/install.rst#3.1-Setup-the-environment

Comment: In the `requirements.txt` there is a line `scipy>=0.19,<0.20` so whenever it sees SciPy 1.0 it tries to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing scipy, at least the version currently required by QISKit, on Windows requires that you have a couple of different compilers installed, which you probably don't. I recommend you install Anaconda. If you download the full Anaconda package, it includes the appropriate scipy binary, or alternatively you can do `conda install scipy=0.19` before you do `pip install qiskit`.

I think that should fix your current issue but feel free to reach out with any others -- I'll be happy to help. You can also find more documentation at [qiskit.org](https://www.qiskit.org/), [github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py), and on the [IBM Q experience community forums](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qstage/#/community).

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: I followed your suggestion using conda install scipy=0.19, but when I tried again pip install qiskit, the same error showed just as before.

Comment: more precisely, the error showed at the first time. seems conda install scipy didn't add scipy into python lib, so pip tried to install scipy  but failed as before. I did find the package under Anaconda's lib.  I also tried to install qiskit on the subsystem. It worked.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. glad you got it to work eventually!

Comment: Oh, sorry for the late reply. I got to prepare for final last two weeks. I'm still wondering why it is not working on Windows, since my laptop using samsung NVMe SSD and not supporting RAID model, so I cannot have Linux on it, and subsystem is not so convenient to use.